# Exception Thrown From Service Not Being Caught in Controller

Tags: exception, grails, stripe-payments

In my Grails service I have code like the following:

```
def createCharge(chargeParams) {
  try {
    def charge = Charge.create(chargeParams)
  } catch (CardException e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

From my controller I do the following:

```
try  {
   service.createCharge(chargeParams)
} catch(CardException e) {

}
```

However, my controller is not catching the re-throwing of the CardException.  If I wrap CardException in a RuntimeException via:

```
throw new RuntimeException(e)
```

and/or remove the signature from the catch to just catch(e) without typing it, it works, but I lose some information from the exception, like the message.

As a note, CardException is an Exception, not a RuntimeException. I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike Java, you don't have to declare the (checked) exceptions that are thrown by a Groovy method, because any undeclared checked exceptions are wrapped in an `UndeclaredThrowableException`. So this:

```
def createCharge(chargeParams) {
  try {
    def charge = Charge.create(chargeParams)
  } catch (CardException e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

is effectively the same as:

```
def createCharge(chargeParams) throws UndeclaredThrowableException {
  try {
    def charge = Charge.create(chargeParams)
  } catch (CardException e) {
    throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(e)
  }
}
```

the exception thrown by the above, obviously wouldn't be caught by:

```
try  {
   service.createCharge(chargeParams)
} catch(CardException e) {

}
```

But it will be caught by:

```
try  {
   service.createCharge(chargeParams)
} catch(e) {

}
```

Because this is just a shorthand for:

```
try  {
   service.createCharge(chargeParams)
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: Well, I need checked exceptions in my case because there are several that I need to deal with from the Stripe API.  I ended up going a different route because I also need to always throw a RuntimeException so my transactions rollback correctly.  I'm marking your answer as correct because it is the right response to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, you can make transactions rollback for all exceptions (checked and unchecked) by adding the following annotation to your Grails services `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable) `

Comment: @Gregg no problem, I generally add this to all my services.

Answer (score 9):

> Unlike Java, you don't have to declare the (checked) exceptions that are thrown by a Groovy method, because any undeclared checked exceptions are wrapped in an UndeclaredThrowableException.

You seem to imply that **Groovy** wraps checked Exceptions by a UndeclaredThrowableException, this is not the case. If a Grails Service throws a unchecked Exception the Exception is eventually wrappped by an UndeclaredThrowableException but this is a java.lang.reflection mechanism and will only occur when a proxy class is involved.

This happens to be the case because a Grails Service is involved. I'm not sure how many proxy classes are exactly involved by there is at least one: a class that does the transaction handling (by Spring).

The class will wrap any method in the Service with a transaction and rollback the transaction when a RuntimeException occurs. Spring transaction management by default doesn't rollback in case of a checked Exception.

**Java**

This makes sense in plain old java, since the developer will see the Exception in the application code and will be warned to do something about it. If the developer is smart he will deal with any Exceptions during the scope of a transaction. If he doesn't rollback the transaction he is basically saying: “In this situation, the data integrity provided by the transaction is not important to me. I will recover from this error in some other way”

**Groovy**

This doesn't make sense in a Groovy world because the Groovy compiler doesn't enforce the dealing with Exceptions. It in effect treats Exceptions exactly the same way as RuntimeExceptions.

There is however a caveat: The reflection mechanism sees an Exception thrown by the proxy that is not in the method signature of the original Service. This is possible because:

1. Groovy doesn't enforce handling the Exceptions
2. A proxy method can always throw any Throwable (check InvocationHandler JavaDoc)

Because the reflection mechanism used is from Java, it must conform to the Java rules. So it will have to wrap the Exception in a RuntimeException,.. in this case a UndeclaredThrowableException.

**Grails**

Now it gets really tricky because if you call your Service method from a Controller and an Exception occurs. You will see a RuntimeException bubble up (because of some hidden mechanism) but your transaction will not be rolled back (because of some hidden mechanism).

This behaviour is **very dangerous** as the developer really has to remember to properly deal with any Exceptions (which the compiler will not help with) or the developer has to make sure that any Service is properly instructed with @Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable).

This is a design issue that I think the developers of Grails have overlooked when they first designed this. But I think the default behaviour is so wrong and so dangerous this should really be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple solution to the problem is to add a `throws CardException` statement to the service method, thus the exception will no longer be wrapped in UndeclaredThrowableException and the controller will catch the proper exception type.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the UndeclaredThrowableException, get the message from it, and then re-throw if need be.

```
catch (UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
    def s = e.getUndeclaredThrowable().getMessage()
    // do something with the message
    throw e
}
```

The above code fragment will just catch the exception you've explicitly thrown in the code (eg CardException).  For example a NullPointerException will not be caught and bubble up.