# Grails - Controller not handling Custom exceptions

Tags: grails

Grails controllers support a simple mechanism for declarative exception handling. If a controller declares a method that accepts a single argument and the argument type is java.lang.Exception or some subclass of java.lang.Exception, that method will be invoked any time an action in that controller throws an exception of that type.

I have just created a Grails application without the kickstart-with-bootstrap plugin and followed the instructions [HERE](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.11/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllerExceptionHandling) from Grails 2.3.11, that is my project's Grails version, and everything goes OK. Why when i have just installed the kickstart plugin this feature of handling Custom Exceptions does not works anymore?

I created a project in Github with an example (commit:65f6d79 -> actual commit and commit: 94a138b -> without kickstart plugin):

github link: https://github.com/cerberous/exception-handler-nokickstart

kickstart's issue: https://github.com/joergrech/KickstartWithBootstrap/issues/94

kickstart plugin documentation page: http://grails.org/plugin/kickstart-with-bootstrap

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, but I think the KWB plugin imposes some custom urlMappings which could be catching your exceptions.

Comment: It is strange, on last commit I have two Controllers the PersonController generated before KWB plugin, that works fine, and the NewPersonController generated after blugin installation and that one does not works. :/

Comment: The https://github.com/cerberous/exception-handler-nokickstart link is currently broken.

Comment: See answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987720/exception-thrown-from-service-not-being-caught-in-controller - this could be a duplicate?